# R package building; how do I get bioconductor packages to install automatically?

Tags: r, installation, bioconductor

I am building an R package that is stored on github that requires several bioconductor packages as imports. During package isntallation, I've noticed that it will automatically install all the CRAN dependencies, but it cannot install the Bioconductor dependencies, which prevents the package from being installed. Is there a way for the package to automatically install bioconductor packages like it does CRAN?

I have considered just writing a script to install the dependencies and providing instructions in the README file to run it before installing my package, but I would really like for it to work automatically for the users. Does anyone have suggestions for things to try?

Comment: How are you installing from github? Are you using `devtools::install_github`? Or something else? What exactly does your DESCRIPTION file look like?

Comment: I am installing from github using devtools::install_github. The description file looks like this:
Depends:
    R (>= 3.4.0)
Imports:
    BiocManager,
    Biostrings,
    dplyr,
    GenomeInfoDb,
    GenomicRanges,
    ggplot2,
    here,
    httr,
    IRanges,
    magrittr,
    openxlsx,
    plyranges,
    reticulate,
    rlang,
    S4Vectors,
    stringr,
    VariantAnnotation
Suggests:
    BSgenome.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg38,
    BSgenome.Mmusculus.UCSC.mm10,

Comment: So you don't have "biocViews:" in your DESCRIPTION file? You should add it.